# Over loading resolution : Mat problem for opening up a camera

Tags: python, opencv

I am quite new to open CV and programming itself, I am unable to run a simple program that opens up my camera because of this mat problem or whatever it is here as you can see.
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Y86r.png)
[My code for opening up the camera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvvbT.png)

Comment: I have tried using a while loop for the imread() part, but the error still persisted .

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.